# disable nginx caching for certain file types

Tags: caching, nginx

I have nginx setup, acting as a reverse proxy to apache.
However, I need to disable caching for gifs.
How can I do this on nginx?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
set $no_cache "";
if ($request_uri ~* \.gif$) {
  set $no_cache "1";
}
proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. Beware though, everyone out there, that **[IF IS EVIL](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)**, at least inside `location` blocks. For everyone else, here are the docs on `if`: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule#if.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that but never ran into any trouble with this case.