# Nginx appears to be caching my index.html, and I can't figure out how to disable it

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I am using nginx with Ubuntu 12.04. I did a basic install to get my web server running in my VM.

I have setup my virtual hosts, installed php5-fpm, etc... and I can run my sites, but in particular my index.html file seems to continuesly get cached. I make a change to it, save and run it and the change appears. But if I do it again, it holds the older version and won't update.

Here is my virtual CONF file for my particular site: http://pastie.org/private/t3ma6bbk8p3hsgqkztdnfa

Here is my nginx.conf

http://pastie.org/8483602

Is there anything that stands out?

Comment: This is an interesting one [anything in here help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236078/how-to-clear-the-cache-of-nginx)

Comment: Yea I read that one..and even set sendfile to off. No go.

Comment: Is it only HTML files that are getting cached?  You could always set [$no_cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403937/disable-nginx-caching-for-certain-file-types) for HTML files but that seems like a bandaid.... Im wondering if the VM is doing it.

Comment: [This link](http://serverfault.com/questions/269420/disable-caching-when-serving-static-files-with-nginx-for-development) may help as well, the guys at Server Fault are probably more help on this than SO.

Comment: I am using VMware Fusion against Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It's weird cause I don't recall running into this issue before.

Comment: here is my header response http://pastie.org/8483688

Comment: Looks like the problem is this: `Expires: Thu, 13 Feb 2014 23:03:55 GMT`

Comment: I have set expires: off and that did not do anything. I am baffled.

Comment: Try setting it to 1 day and see if it changes the header.  It might be ignoring your declaration

Comment: Ok, I just installed a LAMP stack in a new VM, setup new Vhosts...and same result. Here is the actual HTML I am running: http://pastie.org/8483797  is there anything, at all, in there that would indicate I am telling the browser to cache? Because I don't see it

Comment: Ok I ran this and it seems to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that. Typically command + R does a hard refresh for me, but its simply not been working.

Comment: So revisiting. I think my server is fine...but I think there is a delay in writing the file and how its accessed from the VM in a shared folder situation...which I am doing /mnt/hgfs/www  If I sometimes give it 5-10 seconds between saves, it seems to render fine. Still, not sure how to improve this.

Comment: I think this answers that question: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=10067