# How do you disable caching for an nginx+uwsgi+python server?

Tags: python, caching, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to do development of a completely fresh website using exclusively nginx, uwsgi, and python.  The problem is that if I change the file that uwsgi points to, and refresh the page, I get the HTML generated by the previous version of the file.  It seems that nginx, uwsgi, or both are caching the code and/or response of my site.  I have been reading up on uwsgi caching but have not been able to disable caching using the `--cache2` flag and `--cache_*` flags.  I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403937/disable-nginx-caching-for-certain-file-types) and also attempted to use

```
proxy_no_cache "1";
proxy_cache_bypass "1";
```

in the server's location dictionary (located at /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite), but alas it still caches the page.  I have used web2py in the past with nginx and uwsgi and it doesn't seem to have this issue when I updated controllers or views.

This is my site file:

```
server { 
    listen 80 default_server; 
    listen [::]:80 default_server; 
    listen 443 ssl default_server; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server; 
    include snippets/snakeoil.conf; 
    server_name _; 
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params; 
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }
}
```

this is the executed program that the init.d script uses:

```
uwsgi --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --die-on-term -s /tmp/mysock.sock --socket :3031 --uid www-data --gid www-data --vacuum --wsgi-file /path/to/my/python/file.py
```

this is the python file that is loaded:

```
def application(environ, start_response): 
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<h1>Hello World</h1>"]
```

I understand that caching improves performance, so I intend to turn it back on for a production environment, but developing with it turned on is a pain in the butt... What am I doing wrong?

My only workaround right now is to restart the uwsgi service everytime I make a change :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### SOLVED

Alright, I figured it out thanks to Guan Hao.  His comment on web frameworks having an "auto-reload" feature set me on the path of determining how web2py works so seamlessly when modifying controllers, models, and views.  As it turns out, I do have to reload uwsgi before my changes take effect and in the end I found a method (although not the best) that allows me to do development without requiring a shell to issue an `/etc/init.d/mysiteapp restart` everytime I make changes.  According to the uWSGI documentation, there exists a `--touch-reload` flag that you can specify when starting uWSGI that will reload it when a certain file is modified/touched.

```
touch-reload
argument: required_argument
parser: uwsgi_opt_add_string_list
flags: UWSGI_OPT_MASTER
help: reload uWSGI if the specified file is modified/touched
```

I simply set the argument for the flag to a file called `reload` sitting in the root directory of the website and when I upload changes, I simply upload that file as well (at the very end).  It works flawlessly!  Thank you for the tip! I have two days before I can accept my own answer, so if anyone has a better method than this one, please feel free to post it.

--- UPDATE ---

It turns out there is an even better way of doing this!  I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831748/how-to-set-up-autoreload-with-flaskuwsgi) that has a unaccepted answer which solved the issue completely (so far).  With this method I don't even have to touch the `reload` file.  I simply added the following flag and parameter to uwsgi when it is executed in the init.d script:

```
--py-autoreload 1
```

I am not sure why I could never find the answer in Google searches and whatnot, but I could care less now that I have the perfect solution!  Please beware, anyone who uses this, that you should remove the flag in production.

Comment: web2py does have an auto-reload feature, please search `auto-reload` on [the-core](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core) and see the implementation [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/custom_import.py). Auto-reload can be implemented in pure python without aid of uwsgi so that it will work in other wsgi stack like gunicorn etc. as well.

IMHO auto-reload should be enabled only in dev environment, therefore losing some requests during reloading is OK.

Comment: I am not using a framework.  I am only using nginx, uwsgi, and (from the example) a single 3-line python file.  It seems counter-intuitive to not use a framework and then have a framework's logic for auto-reload.  The solution I wanted was one that required the least amount of maintenance and software bloat.  In this case it was solvable by simply adding `--py-autoreload 1` to the executed command.  I upvoted your answer...

Answer (score 2):

It's not caching. You have to restart uwsgi before your changes made to python files take effect.

You may also enable the auto-reload feature of your web framework(web2py or whatever). In that case, the wsgi app will reload itself when it detects file changes, so you don't need to restart uwsgi.

Comment: I am not using a web framework at all.  So, is what you're saying is that I effectively have to setup something like an incron job to monitor the filesystem for changes and restart uwsgi?  That is not feasible because a request could potentially arrive between when the service is stopped and then started again.  I feel like this answer is wrong, but I don't have enough evidence to show that to be the case.  How is it that if I upload changes to a web2py setup, that that code is immediately reflected when I refresh the page without any extra action on my part?  Where is it's "atuo-reload" func?

Comment: Thank you for your answer as it led me in the right direction to get a much better development method.  Please see my answer for more details.